# Highcharts Gantt avoid data overlapping of tasks With Same start and End Date

Tags: highcharts, overlapping, gantt-chart

In Highcharts Data is overlapping when one resource assign multiple tasks with the same start and end time

Please suggest below is the scenario link and code as well

[JS fiddler link for the scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/ssandeep12jain/wtnsLkzc/2/)

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/gantt.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
//Java script 
var today = new Date(),
  day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// Set to 00:00:00:000 today
today.setUTCHours(0);
today.setUTCMinutes(0);
today.setUTCSeconds(0);
today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
today = today.getTime();


// THE CHART
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Grouping tasks vertically'
  },
  yAxis: {
    categories: ['Resource 1', 'Resource 2', 'Resource 3'],
    uniqueNames: true,
        //className: "highcharts-label-icon",
        grid: {
          enabled: true,

        },
        breaks: [{
          breakSize: 0.2,
          from: 0,
          to: 0,
        }],
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Resource 1',
    data: [{
      name: 'Task A',
      y: 0,
      start: today - (2 * day),
      end: today + (6 * day)
    }, {
      name: 'Task B',
      y: 0,
      start: today - (2 * day),
      end: today + (6 * day),
      color: 'rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.7)'
    }, {
      name: 'Task C',
      y: 0,
      start: today + (13 * day),
      end: today + (17 * day)
    }]
  }
  }]
});
```

in that scenario for Resource 1 Task A, B is overlapping

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3fdkm7px/ ?

Comment: I have tried with that but Load event is not supporting the new version of highcharts

Comment: The `load` event is fully supported in the newest version of Highcharts. The demo which I shared uses the actual version which is 8.1.0. API: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/chart.events.load

Comment: Thanks for your input  I am using highchart version 7.2.0 in angular 6 application and in load event property of point graphic not exists in chart.series[0].points[0].graphic.translate(0, -25);

Comment: There is no difference between 7.2.0 and Angular environment. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-so30m

Comment: Thanks, In that Angular Demo you are using different break size and in my condition, the uniqueness is task name only so how I can avoid overlapping any suggestion !!

Comment: I am afraid that without changing the `y` value is impossible. Please take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rb5f7hog/

Comment: Thanks for your Input I have tried to set the value of x.x2 and y for highcharts data but when the chart is loading y value is updated by highcharts - is there any way I stop the value update of y in highcharts.

Comment: Could you reproduce your code in some online editor where I will be able to see described behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for your support in advance- I have tried to reproduce the behavior https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-cache-slkvf?file=/src/app/chart.component.ts:724-733  in above URL Resource 2 have the same start & end time Id is 7 & 8 please read the comment  on ChartData method above id 7 data

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like is done here: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-architecture-1euoq?file=/src/app/chart.component.ts?

Comment: Thanks for Input and your help, yes that I want but it is not showing proper row-wise

Comment: yeah, my mistake, this two points should be moved: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-lehmann-vp6d9

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian, it is working but i have two many points with same time & between time, there is any way we can do dynamic this load event or any other way https://codesandbox.io/s/gantt-chart-overlapping-gn8l8?file=/src/app/chart.component.ts

Comment: I am afraid that this amount of points wouldn't work properly. Have you considered to collapse them? https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gantt/project-management